# Jasmine/karma test failing due to Virtual Scroll on Angular7

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, virtualscroll

**Scenario**:
I am running a very basic test on *Angular7* project (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efdcyc) which also uses *ScrollingModule* within '@angular/cdk/scrolling'.

**Question**: Any way around the error below? am i missing anything?

The simple **test** in my **spec.ts** file

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
        ,countriesComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**Error:**

> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'cdkVirtualForOf' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
>
> ```
> <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="10" class="example-viewport">
>         <div \[ERROR ->\]*cdkVirtualFor="let item of myList" class="example-item">{{item.name}} ({{item.code}})</div>
> </c"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/countriesComponent.html@13:17 Property binding cdkVirtualForOf not used by any directive on an
> ```
>
> embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled
>   correctly and all directives are listed in the
>   "@NgModule.declarations". ("
>
> ```
> <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="10" class="example-viewport">
>         \[ERROR ->\]<div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of myList" class="example-item">{{item.name}} ({{item.code}})</div>   "):
> ```
>
> ng:///DynamicTestModule/countriesComponent.html@13:12
>   'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>
> ```
> \[ERROR ->\]<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="10" class="example-viewport">
>         <div *cdkVirtualFor"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/countriesComponent.html@12:4
> at syntaxError (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1021:1)
> at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse
> ```
>
> (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:14851:1)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
>   (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24570:1)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate
>   (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24557:1)
>       at http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24500:48
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24500:1)
>       at http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24418:1
>       at Object.then (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:1012:33)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents
>   (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js?:24416:1)

[image: Can't bind to 'cdkVirtualForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the module in your testbed.

```
import { ScrollDispatchModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ,countriesComponent
  ], imports: [ScrollDispatchModule]
}).compileComponents();
```

But then again, [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) is there to explain that.